# pre-commit script not returning errors from vagrant box unit tests using -c switch

Tags: git, shell, unit-testing, vagrant, pre-commit-hook

I'm running the following pre-commit script, stored as `.git/hooks/pre-commit`

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "RUNNING UNIT TESTS PRIOR TO COMMIT..."
cd vagrant
RESULT=eval vagrant ssh -c "php /var/www/html/vendor/bin/phpunit -c /var/www/html/app/tests /var/www/html/app/tests"

RED='\033[0;31m'
GREEN='\033[0;32m'
NC='\033[0m'

if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
  printf "${GREEN}Tests Passed!${NC}"
  exit 0
else
  printf "${RED}Tests failed!${NC}"
  exit 1
fi
```

The tests run when I `git commit -m "test message"`, with the following (assuming I have a failing unit test)

```
*****@CSL***:~/close-call/closecall/app$ git commit -m "TEST COMMIT"
RUNNING UNIT TESTS PRIOR TO COMMIT...
PHPUnit 5.0.10 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

E..............................                                   31 / 31 (100%)

Time: 551 ms, Memory: 6.00Mb

There was 1 error:

1) CloseCall\CategoryCollectionTest::test_IsCalled
Argument 1 passed to CloseCall\CategoryCollection::__construct() must be an instance of CloseCall\DataAccess\CategoryCollection, instance of Mock_CategoryCollection_61b28cbf given, called in /var/www/html/app/tests/library/CloseCall/CategoryCollectionTest.php on line 32 and defined

/var/www/html/app/library/CloseCall/CategoryCollection.php:8
/var/www/html/app/tests/library/CloseCall/CategoryCollectionTest.php:32
/var/www/html/app/tests/library/CloseCall/CategoryCollectionTest.php:26

FAILURES!
Tests: 31, Assertions: 59, Errors: 1.
Tests Passed![develop 6bb5b2c] TEST COMMIT
```

However, it's always passing `if [ $? -eq 0]` condition, which should be checking if the error code returned equals 0. It *shouldn't* equal 0 if any tests are failing.

Any idea why it's giving me an error code of 0 (`$?`) even if my tests are failing?

Comment: `$?` is the status of the **last** command. Your `echo` returns true and modifies `$?`. Don't do that or save `$?` in some other variable before printing it, etc.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to even include the echo in the above; I'll remove it - I get the same results with or without the echo.

Comment: The assignments do the same thing.

Comment: `RESULT=eval vagrant ssh -c "php /var/www/html/vendor/bin/phpunit -c /var/www/html/app/tests /var/www/html/app/tests"` is also potentially not what you think it is. That isn't running `vagrant` under `eval` and storing the result in `$RESULT`. It is running vagrant with the `RESULT` variable set to `eval` in its environment. Just FYI.